# make a SpriteNode "jump" sprite kit iOS

Tags: ios, image

I am programming a small game. I've already made that my character is moving by tilting the phone. Now I'd like my character ( an image as a Spritenode ) to jump, when i touch the screen. I still want him to move left and right when I tilt the phone while jumping. What is the best way to do it? I was thinking about making a physicsWorld and then give him a mass and activate gravity.

But how do I let him jump once when i touch the screen?

I'd be happy for all answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: **Do you really need physics ?**

It depends on what you want to do with your game

Physic makes your game more realistic, but is this what you need?

- Does your ground has slopes?
- Is there caves or several floors?
- Can you pass through floors while jumping up? (*Doodle Jump Style*)

---

Your character have a velocity associated, basically a vector with X and Y speed. this velocity is applied each frame of your game loop. to simulate gravity, you remove a very small amount of Y velocity, so it will begin to fall down progressively, faster and faster.
If you want to make your character jump, just apply a relatively high amount of Y velocity.

---

You may want to subclass SKNode to add a velocity property, so you can always know and apply it to his position in the game loop, just think to apply your existing horizontal movement mechanism to the velocity.

Physic handles all of the velocity, forces, angular velocity, physics loop… for you.
If you want to use physics, there's a lot of tutorials online.

You can also browse the [Game Development Stack Overflow Community](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

---

Replace the SKActions with physics:

```
if(shouldMove) {
    SKAction *action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(destX, destY) duration:1];
    [self.sanchez runAction:action];
}
```

by

```
if(shouldMove) {
    [self.sanchez.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(data.acceleration.y * kPlayerSpeed, 0)];
}
```

Comment: im pretty new to xcode and i don't really get that . My game doesn't have to be realistic :D. I just want my character to be able to jump when i touch the screen :)

Comment: That's not specific to Xcode, that's game dev skills/logic. I am editing my post.

Comment: I'd like to try it with physics now , i applied my force in touches began. Then my character jumps and goes back to ground as he should . But i made my x- movement with tilting my phone via coremotion and if i tilt he just stops the jump and moves into the xposition only.. Can i send u some code somewhere?

Comment: Go make some [GithubGist](https://gist.github.com/) or [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) :)

Comment: here is my code  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9f49ede74934c85acc2f
 this is my code for jump and tilt

Comment: but it is not working as it should , i can jump but when i tilt it stops , i just want a hero that can jump and move like in normal games .. :D Can you help me ? :):)

Comment: I updated my response, you should tweak your acceleration, kPlayerSpeed or add an offset to prevent character for always moving.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah making a physics world and giving your character a physics body is a good idea.
To make him jump just apply a force to it using:

```
[yourCharacter.physicsBody applyImpulse:vector]
```

where vector is a CGVector.
Careful with the properties you set for your character's physics body they can be tricky.
You'll have to tweak a bit between the physics world's properties and your character's physics body's properties to get the desired result.

Let me know if something is unclear

EDIT

in your `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method apply the impulse to your character

Comment: when i apply the force to make him jump, I want it to react on touch, what will I use to make that ?

Comment: i am making my character move with the coremotion manager . It works to apply the force and he jumps when i touch and goes back to ground, but if i tilt , the character and gravity stops and moving in the tilting direction . Something's going wrong :/ can i send u some code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Create hero class with this

```
+(id)hero
{
    Hero *hero = [Hero spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"HeroStand"];
    hero.name =@"Hero";
    hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:hero.size];        
    return hero;
}
```

....

```
 -(void)Jump
    {
        if(!self.isJumping)
        {
            [self.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(10,180)];
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"onJump.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
            self.isJumping = YES;
        }
    }
```

and then create instance of hero in your scene

```
 hero = [Hero hero];
    [world addChild:hero];

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
        [hero Jump];

}
```